# Not Fetching Updated Data from API After Deployment only generated statics output showing in angular 17

Tags: angular, deployment, static

After deploying my Angular application, I noticed that the **updated data from the API is not being reflected in the deployed version**. The application was working fine during development and the static pages generated by the Angular CLI at the time of the build displayed the correct data. However, after deployment any changes made to the API are not reflected in the application.

I have verified that the issue persists across multiple browsers and the API itself is functioning correctly when accessed directly. It seems to be a problem specific to the interaction between the deployed Angular application and the API.

**Expected Behaviour:
I expected the Angular v17 to fetch and display the updated data from the API after deployment**